# I want to use TM4C123 TIVA C LaunchPad as a ICSP Arduino programmer

Tags: arduino

The tittle says it all. I recently bought my first arduino board (Arduino Nano), but it results to be a clone an doesn't have a bootloader. I've seen that the only way to burn a bootloader is having a working arduino and connecting them with the ICSP port. Well I haven't any other arduino...

I have a TM4C123 with Energia IDE. I can succesfully upload code with Energia (such as blink example). I thought using the same sketch as the Arduino IDE, the ArduinoISP would simply work, oh boy I was wrong.

My question is, how can I burn the bootloader through Energia with my TM4C123? Is there already a working code that I haven't seen? Which pins should I use?

Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 0):

a quick google search gave me this

-https://hackaday.com/2012/05/03/ti-launchpad-as-avr-isp-programmer/

what you want is an isp programmer.
you can use pretty much anything for it. the protocol is very similar to spi, on avrs even using the spi pins.
but it might be more promising getting a cheap usb/isp programmer or an arduino that works... especially on windows.